# What other permissions are needed for a user to update the field apart from Read/write access?

Tags: apex, permissions, profile, permission-sets

I have been receiving this error message while updating one field for which the user has already been given the READ/WRITE permissions. Need help with what extra permissions are required. Note - The record id in the error points to the Account object.

```
 Following errors for the object Account :
UPDATE Error - Record No: 2 , Record Id: XXXXX000004XXXXXX , Error Message:  Error Status Code:  INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY
Error Message:  insufficient access rights on object id
```

Comment: Are you getting only for that particular field or for all the fields?

Comment: I am updating only one field so I cannot say if it's happening for other fields as only one field has access to Read/Write.

Comment: This type or error is usually to do with sharing. Basically the user only has read access to the specific record you are trying to update (or has no access at all).

Comment: Yes as highlighted by @PhilW, Can you check if user have required access to edit it using below query. `SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasTransferAccess, MaxAccessLevel
     FROM UserRecordAccess
     WHERE UserId = [single ID]
     AND RecordId = [single ID]  `

Comment: Sure let me check and revert.